# Src of an iframe as a variable with values from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, iframe

I want to display the site selected by the user from dropdown in an iframe in my webpage. I have values of the website links and the corresponding sitenames in a database. I have tried the following code.

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','pass','db_name');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<script>
      function goToPage763(mySelect){
          frames['iframe2'].location.src = $(mySelect).val();
      }
</script>";
echo '<select id="size" onchange="goToPage763(this.value)">'; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$row['Website'].'">'.$row['Marketplace'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';// 
echo "";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the html code affected by the php is

```
<select id="username" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a seller"  onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person...</option>
<option value="1">Butterflyfields</option>
</select>
<label for="seller">Marketplace: </label>
<select name="txtHint" id="txtHint" onchange="getSrc(this.value)" target="iframe2">
</select>
```

the code for iframe is

```
<iframe runat="server" id="iframe2" src="https://localhost/sim.php" height="680" width="100%" frameborder="1" allowTransparency="true">
 <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

my problem is that i'm unable to do it, display link of selected value in the frame from database.

Comment: Could you please specify your problem? Which part of your example doesn't work? Please also add the `HTML` code of your `iframe`. Maybe also add the `HTML` code that is generated by your `PHP` script.

Comment: the src file of iframe has nothing

Comment: The `HTML` code in your questions doesn't fit to the output in your `PHP`  code.

Comment: i have a dropdown in which when i am selecting a user, the relevant marketplaces from the database is showing in another dropdown, now i want to display the site of the marketplace which i select from the dropdown generated in the iframe. I have the url and the name of the marketplace in another table in same database

Comment: the html code i have shown is for the part part, i.e., displaying the second dropdown

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery to achieve this like:

```
//put this after jquery.js
$('#txtHint').change(function() {
   //set the iframe's src to the value from the selected option.
   $('#iframe2').attr('src',$(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you share the options markup that is generated please.

Comment: i have a dropdown in which when i am selecting a user, the relevant marketplaces from the database is showing in another dropdown, now i want to display the site of the marketplace which i select from the dropdown generated in the iframe. I have the url and the name of the marketplace in another table in same database

Comment: for the script in my answer to work the marketplace select should have options like this
<option value="google.com">Google</option>

Comment: yeah! i knw how to do that! but i'm getting the values of the marketplaces after selecting the seller from the first dropdown(which means the downdown is variable). so i have set the value as the value in website column of my table for the marketplace name displayed in the same table.